# Converting Geojson nested array data and printing it as a list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, geojson

I am trying to convert a GeoJson data into jquery and print specific values.
Below mentioned is the JSONcode.

```
 {

 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "metadata": 
  {
  "generated": 1445482204000,
  "url": "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?  
  format=geojson&starttime=2015-01-01&endtime=2015-01-02",
  "title": "USGS Earthquakes",
  "status": 200,
  "api": "1.0.17",
  "count": 343
  },
 "features": [
  {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "mag": 2.51,
    "place": "21km ESE of Coso Junction, California"
   }
   }
   ]
   }
```

Below mentioned is my JSON file i want to print the key "place" present in the "properties" present in a  "features" array in jquery.

Below mentioned is my effort:

```
    $("#button2").click(function(){
    $.get("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/count?
    format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21",
    function(data,status){
    $.each(data.features.properties, function (i, ob) {
    $.each(ob, function (ind, obj) {
    console.log("key:" + ind + " value:" + obj);
    });
    });

   });
   });
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="Sesimic_Events">
   <button id="button2">Places affected</button>
```

Below mentioned is the error i got

```
 TypeError: data.features is undefined
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: going to the actual url, you notice you get this: {"count":2111,"maxAllowed":20000}

Comment: btw... if you get data ... update your answer so i can get data too, i always have a hard time pulling data

Comment: @Daemedeor what i want is the place value present in the properties array

Comment: i know, but when you do a $.get(), i'm literally getting back that json.... are you sure that data is there?

Comment: @Daemedeor  I  assume the  term "data" in the  code is nothing but a  json object and what i am trying is to convert those nested arrays in json to jquery and print them.For which i wrote the following code .

Comment: it is a json object, a json object that shoots out: Object {count: 2114, maxAllowed: 20000}, so i think you're pinging the wrong API

Comment: check this fiddle (the console): http://jsfiddle.net/527u8yps/

Comment: @Daemedeor can you explain it further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93028/discussion-between-daemedeor-and-mohan-babu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your basic error is that in your $.get method, you're calling to their API for the count at 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/count?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21' which would not return the objects you want as shown above. you really want to ping this address: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21 for their actual data so you can go through and get the information....

so it should really be

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
    $.get("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21",
    function(data, status) {
    $.each(data.features.properties, function (i, ob) {
        $.each(ob, function (ind, obj) {
           console.log("key:" + ind + " value:" + obj);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

but this brings up other errors noticably, that the object you're hooking up to is really an array so data.features = [{},{}.{}]; so data.features.properties will still be undefined. cause i'm going to use this data too, i figured i'll help you parse it the way you're expecting:

```
$.get("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21",
function (data, status) {

    $.each(data.features, function(index, object){
        $.each(object.properties, function(i,obj){
            console.log("key: ", i, " value: ", obj);
        });
    });

});
```

The biggest thing is DON'T ASSUME the data is correct if you're getting errors from a get, just do a harmless console.log(data); to ensure that your data is coming through as expected!